# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/security/authorize/RefreshAuthorizationPolicyProtocol

Tags: hadoop

I am currently trying to install hadoop 2.3.0 on my cluster. However, when I run command "bin/hdfs namenode -format", I got this error:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/security/authorize/RefreshAuthorizationPolicyProtocol

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hadoop.security.authorize.RefreshAuthorizationPolicyProtocol

Any ideas how to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

There isn't much information in the question, but this error will occur if the environment variable HADOOP_COMMON_HOME is not correctly set to $HADOOP_HOME (the top level where HADOOP is installed).